# GCM - no devices registered

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Have a problem with implementing GCM.

Server side i used the HTTP method. Created the war file and uploaded it to apache tomcat (only changed the API in "samples/gcm-demo-server/WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/api.key" with the server api from the dev console). When i access the page i get a "No devices registered!".

Implemented the Android part as well, hit the register button, got a response from GCM with the registeredId, thus, i presume that the device got registerd in teh GCM. The problem comes when i go back to my webpage and I see the same message: "No devices registered".

Tried to look for similar errors, but only found *old* GCM api implementations.

Have any idea for a way to figure out if the problem comes from my server, the gcm server or it's something bad with the android part itself?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you should fill `SERVER_URL` in `gcm-demo-client/src/com/google/android/gcm/demo/app/CommonUtilities.java`

and check whatever the HTTP call to the servlet `http://Your-IP/register` is really executed after the GCM registration to Google in order to let the gcm-demo-server, that you are using, to run correctly and send the push notification to that Registration ID.

Don't forget to keep the server running because it saves RegIDs in memory through the `Datastore` class

Comment: but hasn't this been deprecated? https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/helper.html

Comment: Yes, I thought you were trying to use that, you should use definitely this Gradle based example https://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/gcm-client/GcmClient/src/main/java/com/google/android/gcm/demo/app/DemoActivity.java or just rely on the GCM code snippet and implement the HTTP call to the Registration Servlet `sendRegistrationIdToBackend()`

Comment: I managed to register the device(got the registeredId), but when i access the gcm server from my tomcat, i get a no devices available message.

Comment: Solved. Was a problem in my send implementation. Working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
private void sendRegistrationIdToBackend() throws Exception {
    // Your implementation here.
    String URL="http://Your_Server_IP/gcm-demo/register?regId="+SENDER_ID;
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(URL));
    StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
    if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
        String responseString = out.toString();
        out.close();
        //..more logic
    } else{
        //Closes the connection.
        response.getEntity().getContent().close();
        throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
    }
}
```